# Liaison between French names and surnames

Tags: prononciation, liaisons, prénoms

Is liaison between French names and surnames used? For example, if a Francois has a surname starting with a vowel, is it pronounced as Francois or Francoise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is never a liaison between a first and a last name so ***François*** is never pronounced ***Françoise***.

E.g.: François Ozon, Jean Amadou